# Split views in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

How can I have split views for the editor page and PDF page in TexStudio?
I would like to use each of them in on display.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the "windowed viewer"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the `View` button. It is a magnifying glass over a white page icon, right next to `Stop Compile` (green square).